# Deconstruct Container containing ValueTuple in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, valuetuple

I am able to deconstruct a container via an extension method:

```
var limits = new[] { MyEnum.A , MyEnum.B , MyEnum.C }
        .ToDictionary( x => x ,
                       x => ( SupportedLimit: GetLimit( x ) , RequiredLimit: 0 ) );

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Deconstruct<TKey, TVal>(
        this KeyValuePair<TKey , TVal> tuple ,
        out TKey key , out TVal value )
    {
        key = tuple.Key;
        value = tuple.Value;
    }

    public static void Deconstruct<TKey, TVal1, TVal2>(
        this KeyValuePair<TKey , (TVal1,TVal2)> tuple ,
        out TKey key , out TVal1 v1 , out TVal2 v2 )
    {
        key = tuple.Key;
        (v1 , v2) = tuple.Value;
    }
}

// works
foreach( var ( enumVal , supportedLimit , requiredLimit ) in limits )
    Debugger.Break();
```

How do I deconstruct a container/dictionary containing a `System.ValueTuple` in LINQ?

```
// won't work, .Where() expects Func<T,bool> not Func<T1,T2,T3,bool>

var failedLimits = limits.Where( ( _ , sup , req ) => sup < req );
```

I just wanted to know how (and if) it is possible to deconstruct the ValueTuple in (any) LINQ method. I guess I have to add an extension method for every Linq-method (List-like) + overloads for dictionaries + each amount of values in the ValueTuple.
How would it look like for the Where() in the example?

Comment: Well first you need to undersatnd that a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

Comment: And how `Where` extension method works.

Comment: No you don't need to add extentions method for every Linq method.  Just use the named parameters of your value tuple.  That's the whole point of why they exist.  Deconstruction should only be needed when assigning the value tuple to multiple variables (typically on the return of a method).  There's no need for it in a lambda expression, at least not that I can see.

Comment: Also make sure you're using value tuples in the right place.  Other options are the reference Tuple, anonymous classes or just a plain old custom class.  Each one has a preferred use case.  Specifically value tuples are great for ridding code of out parameters, so maybe you should use them as the return type on your extension methods instead.

Comment: @juharr I find `limits.Where( ( _ , sup , req ) => sup < req );` more readable/terse than `limits.Where( kvp => kvp.Value.RequiredLimit < kvp.Value.SupportedLimit );`

Comment: @nonsensation Terse, yes.  Readable, no.  `SuppoertedLimit` is much or clear that `sup` in what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,(T1,T2)>> Where<TKey,T1,T2>(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,(T1,T2)>> source ,
        Func<TKey,T1,T2, Boolean> predicate )
        => source.Where( predicate );
}
```

- Overloads for List-like types + every amount of ValueTuple-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with a `Dictionary` the values you iterate over are `KeyValuePair`s.  You need to deal with the `Value` part of the `KeyValuePair` and then just use the named property of your value tuple.

```
var failedLimits = limits.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.SupportedLimit < req);
```